# Flawed argument in the proof of function extensionality in cubical type theory?

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I am reading the lectures about cubical type theory in this [github repo](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt). In [lecture 1](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt/blob/master/lectures/lecture1.ctt#L451) the author defines function extensionality the following way:

```
funExt (A B : U) (f g : A -> B)
       (p : (x : A) -> Path B (f x) (g x)) :
       Path (A -> B) f g = <i> \(a : A) -> (p a) @ i
```

and writes

```
To see that this makes sense compute the end-points of the path:

  (<i> \(a : A) -> (p a) @ i) @ 0 = \(a : A) -> (p a) @ 0
                                  = \(a : A) -> f a
                                  = f
```

I don't follow. Specifically, when we replace `(p a) @ 0` with `f a` in my mind we use the following fact: `\(a : A) -> (p a) @ 0 = f a` to rewrite (let's give names to the left and right side) `fpa = \(a : A) -> (p a) @ 0` into `fa = \(a : A) -> f a`. But isn't this by itself *using* function extensionality with `f = fpa, g = fa`?

If I am not mistaken, this argument is circular. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression:

```
\(a : A) -> (p a) @ 0
```

parses as:

```
\(a : A) -> ((p a) @ 0)
```

So this is applying `p a : Path B (f a) (g a)` to the `0` point. This reduces to `f a`, because it is the beginning point of the path. It's essentially doing the same thing as the earlier step, which beta reduced the `(<i> ...) @ 0` to `(...)[i := 0]`, except `p a` looks abstract to us, *but* that doesn't matter, because we know what it reduces to when applied to `0` (or `1`) based only on its type.

So, it's not using function extensionality to prove extensionality. What it's doing is taking advantage of the fact that `Path` types are similar to function types, and that the two `Path` types in `funExt` are 'just' functions with different argument order (so it flips them).

Comment: Would it be correct to say that because `(p a) @ 0` is judgementally equal to `(f a)` we are allowed to rewrite it inside the lambda? So the difference is judgemental vs path equality. Makes sense to me.

Comment: I think that is correct to say. Expressions where a path is applied to `0` or `1` are judgmentally equal to the corresponding end point of the path, even though for arbitrary `i` you may not know the value.